# changing fullcalendar's events option using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar plugin to display available rooms.

> ```
> <script>
>     var $c = jQuery.no
>
>     Conflict();
>       $c(document).ready(function() {
>
>           $c('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>               monthNames: ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
>               dayNamesShort: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
>               height: 530,
>               theme: true,
>               firstDay: 1,
>               month:8,
>
>               events: "json-events.php?roomtype_id=5<?//=$_GET['rtype']?>",
>               eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
>                   alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
>                       '(should probably update your database)');
>               },
>
>               loading: function(bool) {
>                   if (bool) $c('#loading').show();
>                   else $c('#loading').hide();
>               }
>
>           });
>
>       });
>
>    </script>
> ```

and I have a selectbox.

```
<select name="side_room_type" id="room_type" class="input-medium">
    <option value="0">Select Room Type</option>
    <option value="5">Family Room</option>
    <option value="7">Seaside Rooms</option>
</select>
```

I can display available rooms by using;

events: "json-events.php?roomtype_id=xxx"

and getting data from it. 
I am trying to get the selected option value and change the "events" value using it. If Seaside Room is selected it should change events from this:

events: "json-events.php?roomtype_id=5

to this:

events: "json-events.php?roomtype_id=7

and of course it should get available rooms without refreshing the page.

I will be glad if you can help me with this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the methods "removeEventsSource" and "addEventSource".
Look at : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/

```
var url = 'json-events.php?roomtype_id=';
var old_id = 5;

$('#room_type').change(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', url + old_id);

    old_id = $(this).val();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', url + old_id);
});
```

Of course, this is only the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My ajax knowledge is little bit limited. I added your codes before mine when I change select option it says Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'calendar'... 
Where should I put the code that you have send? Can you post the full code please?

Comment: `$('#calendar').calendar(...)` should be `$('#calendar').fullCalendar(...)`

Comment: I changed $('#calendar').calendar to $('#calendar').fullCalendar but this time nothing happens when I change the select options

Comment: I edited my first post. Can you please look at the latest change at the bottom and tell where I am doing wrong?

Comment: There are two errors: it should be `fullCalendar` with a capital C, and `removeEventSource` and `addEventSource`. I will update Vincent's answer accordingly.

Comment: I have realize that if I change select options too quickly before json-events.php loaded, removeEventSource  doesn't remove the old event. [please see the screenshot](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/5144/ops0.png). Any successions?

Comment: You can make sure that is's not possible to change the room type while the calendar is loading events. Check out this FullCalendar callback: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/

Comment: I added
$c('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');   
after removeEventSource an it worked.